# How to merge legends for color and shape when geom_hline has a separate (additional) entry in the color legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I have the following code, which produces the following plot:

```
cols <- brewer.pal(n = 3, name = 'Dark2')

p4 <- ggplot(all.m, aes(x=xval, y=yval, colour = Approach, ymax = 0.95)) + theme_bw() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= yval - se, ymax = yval + se), width=5, position=pd) + 
  geom_line(position=pd) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=Approach, colour = Approach), size = 4) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = cp.best$slope, colour = "C2P"), show_guide = FALSE) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Approach", breaks=c("C2P", "P2P", "CP2P"), values =  cols[c(1,3,2)]) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.4, 0.95, 0.05), "Test AUROC") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 150, by = 20), "# Number of Patient Samples in Training")
p4 <- p4 + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
      legend.position = 'top', 
      plot.margin = unit(c(5.1, 7, 4.5, 3.5)/2, "lines"), 
      text = element_text(size=15), axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=-1.5), axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=2))   
p4 <- p4 + guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=c(NA,17,16))))

p4
```

[image]
When I try `show_guide = FALSE` in `geom_point`, the shape of the point in the upper legend are all set to default solid circles.

How can I make the lower legend to disappear, without affecting the upper legend?

Comment: Could you describe your data & goals a little bit more? Is this correct: you have 3 Approaches (C2P, P2P, and CP2P), and for 2 of those (P2P, CP2P), the yvalue varies by the xval. For C2P, the yval is always 0.66. You want to plot (1) lines & points for P2P and CP2P, (2) a line only for C2P, and (3) a legend that shows all three Approaches in one box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution, complete with reproducible data:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")
library("RColorBrewer")

cp2p <- data.frame(xval = 10 * 2:15, yval = cumsum(c(0.55, rnorm(13, 0.01, 0.005))), Approach = "CP2P", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
p2p <- data.frame(xval = 10 * 1:15, yval = cumsum(c(0.7, rnorm(14, 0.01, 0.005))), Approach = "P2P", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

pd <- position_dodge(0.1)
cp.best <- list(slope = 0.65)

all.m <- rbind(p2p, cp2p)
all.m$Approach <- factor(all.m$Approach, levels = c("C2P", "P2P", "CP2P"))
all.m$se <- rnorm(29, 0.1, 0.02)
all.m[nrow(all.m) + 1, ] <- all.m[nrow(all.m) + 1, ] # Creates a new row filled with NAs
all.m$Approach[nrow(all.m)] <- "C2P"
cols <- brewer.pal(n = 3, name = 'Dark2')

p4 <- ggplot(all.m, aes(x=xval, y=yval, colour = Approach, ymax = 0.95)) + theme_bw() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= yval - se, ymax = yval + se), width=5, position=pd) + 
  geom_line(position=pd) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=Approach, colour = Approach), size = 4, na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = cp.best$slope, colour = "C2P")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c(C2P = cols[1], P2P = cols[2], CP2P = cols[3])) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(C2P = NA, P2P = 16, CP2P = 17)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.4, 0.95, 0.05), "Test AUROC") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 150, by = 20), "# Number of Patient Samples in Training")
p4 <- p4 + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
                 legend.position = 'top', 
                 plot.margin = unit(c(5.1, 7, 4.5, 3.5)/2, "lines"), 
                 text = element_text(size=15), axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=-1.5), axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=2))   
p4
```

[image: Plot of example]

The trick is to make sure that all of the desired levels of `all.m$Approach` appear in `all.m`, even if one of them gets dropped out of the graph. The warning about the omitted point is suppressed by the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to `geom_point`.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
Just add a dummy `geom_point` layer (transparent points) where `shape` is mapped to the same `level` as in `geom_hline`.

```
geom_point(aes(shape = "int"), alpha = 0)
```

**Longer answer:**
Whenever possible, `ggplot` merges / combines legends of different `aes`thetics. For example, if `colour` and `shape` is mapped to the same variable, then the two legends are combined into one.

I illustrate this using simple data set with 'x', 'y' and a grouping variable 'grp' with two levels:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:2, 2), y = 1:4, grp = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2))
```

First we map both `color` and `shape` to 'grp'

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp, shape = grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 4)
```

[image]

Fine, the legends for the `aes`thetics, `color` and `shape`, are merged into one.

Then we add a `geom_hline`. We want it to have a separate color from the `geom_line`s *and* to appear in the legend. Thus, we *map* `color` to a variable, i.e. put `color` inside `aes` of `geom_hline`. In this case we do not map the color to a variable in the data set, but to a constant. We may give the constant a desired name, so we don't need to rename the legend entries afterwards.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp, shape = grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 2.5, color = "int"))
```

[image]

Now two legends appears, one for the `color` `aes`thetics of `geom_line` and `geom_hline`, and one for the `shape` of the `geom_point`s. The reason for this is that the "variable" which `color` is mapped to now contains three levels: the two levels of 'grp' in the original data, *plus* the level 'int' which was introduced in the `geom_hline` `aes`. Thus, the levels in the `color` scale differs from those in the `shape` scale, and by default ggplot can't merge the two scales into one legend.

How to combine the two legends?

**One possibility** is to introduce the same, additional level for `shape` as for `color` by using a dummy `geom_point` layer with transparent points (`alpha` = 0) so that the two `aes`thetics contains the same levels:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp, shape = grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 2.5, color = "int")) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = "int"), alpha = 0) # <~~~~ a blank geom_point
```

[image]

**Another possibility** is to convert the original grouping variable to a `factor`, and add the "`geom_hline` level" to the original levels. Then use `drop = FALSE` in `scale_shape_discrete` to include "unused factor levels from the scale":

```
datadf$grp <- factor(df$grp, levels = c(unique(df$grp), "int"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp, shape = grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 2.5, color = "int")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

Then, as you already know, you may use the `guides` function to "`override`" the `shape` `aes`thetics in the legend, and remove the shape from the `geom_hline` entry by setting it to `NA`:

```
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 17, NA))))
```